# In mvc pattern how to show another view

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller

Hi im developing an winform application using mvc pattern,

If i have a windows form as a view with a button in it, and i want to show another view(winform) on click of button in the first form.

In this case whether the view should should notify the button click to the controller and the contoller will instantiate the second form and show or the first view itself will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller should probably handle it. In the purest form of the MVC pattern, views should be for displaying their own content, and any other logic, including displaying other views, is up to the controller. (In fact, for many actions, that is all the controller ends up doing.)